# How to narrow Get-WinEvent query?

Tags: powershell

I need the following code:

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
   LogName = 'Security'
   ID = 4688
} | Select-Object @{name='NewProcessName';expression={ $_.Properties[5].Value }})
```

To match a specific process name, say 'cmd.exe' for example, and return the most recent record found.  Maybe using Where-Object?  Not a PowerShell expert, so need some help.

Comment: Maybe [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the initial event list with XPATH.  For example, to get all 'pwsh.exe' events, use:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4688] and EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName']='C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe']]" -LogName 'Security'
```

Unfortunately, `Get-WinEvent` supports a [very limited version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/consuming-events#xpath-10-limitations) of XPATH, so you can't do anything very sophisticated (e.g. regex match), but you could get the latest event using PowerShell:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4688] and EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName']='C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe']]" -LogName 'Security' |
    Sort-Object TimeCreated -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1
```

Since the XPATH implementation is so limited, using wildcards, etc, with the process name won't work, but you can just use PowerShell for filtering instead:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName = 'Security'; ID = 4688} |
    Where-Object {$_.Properties[5].Value -like '*svchost.exe'} |
    Sort-Object TimeCreated -Descending |
    Select-Object ID, TimeCreated, @{Label = 'ProcessName'; Expression = {$_.Properties[5].Value.Split('\')[-1]}}
```

Which will give all the matching events in order of most recent first:

```
  Id TimeCreated         ProcessName
  -- -----------         -----------
4688 15/11/2023 12:21:54 svchost.exe
4688 15/11/2023 12:19:51 svchost.exe
4688 15/11/2023 12:19:25 svchost.exe
4688 15/11/2023 12:19:25 svchost.exe
4688 15/11/2023 12:19:25 svchost.exe
4688 15/11/2023 12:19:25 svchost.exe
```

If you just want the single most recent item, add `-First 1` to the end of `Select-Object`.

Comment: Is there a way to match a substring against the NewProcessName value?  Say just 'pwsh.exe' rather than the explicit full string, i.e. path?  My question qualified just the file name, i.e. cmd.exe versus a full path.

Comment: Not with XPATH, but I updated my answer to show how to filter using PowerShell functionality.

Comment: Now that is really slick!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter any named event data value (although it will match ParentProcessName too).

```
Get-WinEvent @{LogName = 'Security';ID = 4688; 
  data = 'C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe' } | 
  % { [xml]$xml = $_.toxml(); $xml.event.eventdata.data | 
    ? name -eq newprocessname }

Name           #text
----           -----
NewProcessName C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe
```

In powershell 7 you can be more specific which event data, the one named "NewProcessName":

```
Get-WinEvent @{LogName = 'Security';ID = 4688; 
  NewProcessName = 'C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe' } |
   % { [xml]$xml = $_.toxml(); $xml.event.eventdata.data | 
     ? name -eq newprocessname }

Name           #text
----           -----
NewProcessName C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe
```

The complete list of event data looks like this:

```
Name               #text
----               -----
SubjectUserSid     S-1-5-18
SubjectUserName    -
SubjectDomainName  -
SubjectLogonId     0x3e7
NewProcessId       0x3d8
NewProcessName     C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe
TokenElevationType %%1936
ProcessId          0x318
CommandLine
TargetUserSid      S-1-0-0
TargetUserName     -
TargetDomainName   -
TargetLogonId      0x0
ParentProcessName  C:\Windows\System32\wininit.exe
MandatoryLabel     S-1-16-16384
```